# TypeError: perform_create() does not have 1 required positional argument'serializer' I am getting an error like this

Tags: python, django

view.py

```
from rest_framework import viewsets, permissions, generics, serializers
from .serializers import PlayerSerializer
from .models import PlayerList
from rest_framework.response import Response

class PostPlayer(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = PlayerList.objects.all().order_by('-d_code')
    serializer_class = PlayerListSerializer

    def perform_create(self, request, serializer):
        d_code = request.data.get('h_code') + 'test'
        #do something with d_code
        new_code = d_code + 'someSampleValue'
        serializer.save(d_code=new_code)
```

TypeError: perform_create() does not have 1 required positional argument'serializer' I am getting an error like this.

Any idea why I am getting this error?

Let me know what I am missing now.

[This is an example of perform_create](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#methods)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your **`perform_create(...)`** method as,

```
class PostPlayer(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = PlayerList.objects.all().order_by('-d_code')
    serializer_class = PlayerListSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        d_code = self.request.data.get('h_code') + 'test'
        # do something with d_code
        new_code = d_code + 'someSampleValue'
        serializer.save(d_code=new_code)
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you please explain what was the problem?

Comment: You have added a ***positional parameter (`request`)*** to the `perform_create(...)` , and which is not supposed to be there.